# Using on() to trigger a form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to bind this submit event from a form which not always be in Dom, so I trying with `.on()`:

```
$('body').on("form","submit", function(e){})
```

but firebug logs:

> $("body").on is not a function
>       [Parar en este error]
>
> $('body').on("form","submit", function(e){

tried also

```
$(document).on("form","submit", function(e){})
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.7 or newer? Is jQuery loaded when you run that code? You need to swap `form` and `submit` around as well.

Comment: You are probably using an old version of jQuery and you also need to change the order of the selector and the event.

Comment: omg! that is it! i am using <1.7... thanks!

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet If you are not interested in upgrading, and you are using 1.4.2 or newer, http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ might be right for you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are upgrading to jQuery 1.7, you can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) by applying `form` as a selector, like:

`$('body').on("submit", "form", function(e){`

Which will bind the `submit` event to `body`, but filtering it to `form` which works the same way as the `delegate` example below.

If you are using 1.4.2 or newer, you can use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) like this:

`$('body').delegate("form", "submit", function(e){`

Comment: +1 yep, the correct syntax is `.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )`, however it would be better to apply `.on()` to a specific container if possible while bubbling through the whole `body` may be unnecessary  ...like: `$("#wrapperwheremyformwillbe").on("submit","form", function(e){});`

Comment: @JFK Right you are, the more specific the selector, the better. However, with the information he provided, can't really provide any more accurate answer.

Comment: well, the comment was more oriented to the OP. your answer is perfect within the context and this is why I voted it up ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the form and use `on` to bind the event listener.

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function(e){} );
```

You also need jQuery version 1.7 or higher to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: - OP needs delegation  for future form

Comment: This won't work. He wants to use event delegation because he adds the form dynamically to the DOM (if I understood him right)

Comment: Ah, okay, then Niklas has the right answer. I misunderstood the question.